# Read a file in specific location and replace all occurence of single quotes to &#39 in c#

Tags: c#, string, file

I need to read a file in specific location and find all the occurence of single quote and replace it by &#39 in c#

```
string file = @"D:\MyDirectory\MyFile.po";
```

Say this is my file, I have to read this and replace all single quote  by &#39.

Comment: Please include the code you have written to attempt this and tell us what's not working

Comment: Duplicate! This question has been answered at least 4 times on stackoverflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509532/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-with-c-sharp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915632/open-a-file-and-replace-strings-in-c-sharp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615624/c-sharp-replace-string-in-a-text-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239095/replacing-a-certain-word-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 4):

You can use the System.IO Library, and read it into an array, replace each instance and then write it back to the file

```
string file = @"D:\MyDirectory\MyFile.po";
string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
for(int i = 0; i < allLines.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    allLines[i] = allLines[i].Replace("'",@"&#39");
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file,allLines);
```

Alternatively you can use ReadAllText, which returns the entire file's contents as a single string, which removes the requirement to loop

```
string file = @"D:\MyDirectory\MyFile.po";
string allText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
allText = allText.Replace("'",@"&#39");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file,allText);
```

Comment: @Default Yes sorry, my mistake! All are fixed now - I was a little absent minded and it was off the top of my head :)

Comment: second example is simplier, but in case of large file, it could lead to performance issues.